# Linq: group by with a non-unique key (preserving order)

Tags: linq

Suppose the list is like a-a-a-b-b-a-c-c-c-a-a, how do I get the groups 
{a-a-a}-{b-b}-{a}-{c-c-c}-{a-a}?

So not what I want is: {a-a-a-a-a-a}-{b-b}-{c-c-c}.

Comment: what have you tried to solve the problem?

Comment: linq might not be the right answer here.

Comment: I had a short look at `Observable.GroupByUntil` in `System.Reactive.Linq` namespace. I couldn't make sense of it, neither the namespace. And I thought: well maybe I overlook a certain Linq possibility, otherwise I thought of 1 enumeration of the list to create a list of lists and go from there.

Comment: B.t.w. I wonder what is wrong with such a simple question to get a -1 and a close vote? Just asking because I don't get that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    public static List<(string key, List<T> items)> GroupByConsecutive<T>( 
          IEnumerable<T> items,   
          Func<T, string> key)
    {
        var list = new List<(string key, List<T> items)>();

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            if (list.Count == 0 || list.Last().key != key(item))
            {
                list.Add((key(item), new List<T> { item }));
            }
            else
            {
                list.Last().items.Add(item);
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code;

```
var list = new List<string>
{
    "a","a","a","b","b","a","c","c","c","a","a"
};
int index = 0;
string lastItem = "";
var groupedList = 
    list
    .Select(x =>
    {
        if (lastItem != x)
        {
            index++;
            lastItem = x;
        }
        return new { Item = x,Index = index };
    })
    .GroupBy(grp => grp)
    .Select(grp => grp.Select(x => x.Item).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

**Output**

```
a,a,a
b,b
a
c,c,c
a,a
```

Comment: I think it is clever, at the same time not human-readable at least I don't get it in less then a minute ... thank for your effort, I go with 2 explicit enumerations.